# how to select a date from a cell to be inputted into macro? or to put current date as a selection

Tags: excel, vba, date

so im doing a macro to draw data from a sheet, however, i need it tot be current as i need to update the sheet daily, currently im updating by per month. is there a way i can input (today)/current date into the macro so i do not have to change every mth in the macro.

this is what i used.

```
Sheets("Form1").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2                     'clear date
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=25                    'clear status
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9                     'clear name
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11                    'clear before improvement
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "4/1/2021")                         'TBU, filter date(mar)
```

Comment: `Criteria:=Date` may do the job. As an alternative try `Criteria:= Format(Date, "m/d/yyyy")` or a variation thereof. It depends upon what Field #2 contains. Either way, `Debug.Print Date` prints the current date in the "Short date" format set in your computer's International Settings.

Comment: so basically, i need to count data by month, so every end of month i need to go into marco to edit the mth for the vba to run.. so instead of going into macro to edit, can i instead edit from any sheets or cells such that it can be updated to the months i wanna collate the data from?

Comment: In place of `Date` or `Format(Date, "mm/ddyyyy")` you can use you can use a reference like `Sheet1.Cells(2, "A").Value` or `Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Value, "mm/ddyyyy")`.

Comment: it doesnt work..

Comment: Your comment is not useful. Please describe what you have done and what was the result of it. Just to remind you, your question was "is there a way i can input (today)/current date into the macro'. I showed you the way. Now the question is how you implemented my advice.

Comment: ok sorry.. basically, i have a table where people will update something everyday. and my job is to collate the data on a daily basis, and have it compiled in another sheet within the same workbook. currently what im doing is to pull the results on a monthly basis as seen on my initial post. and it will only filter by the month that i wanna find.

Comment: however, what i wanna do is, instead of going into the macros monthly to change the month(date), is there a way i can change it by keying in on the excel sheet instead. i tried your method, but it is only pulling data from that very day the date shown, its not consolidated data, so meaning if the date is today, and there is no input data, it will show 0 on my table. thanks

Comment: Yes, I thought you want a single day. I imagine you have a long list and you want all entries of one month and, now, of one day. Where am I wrong? I already showed you how to hard-code the current date or take any date you enter in a cell. What do you want if the specified day's result is zero?

Comment: ok nevermind thanks. you are not wrong. maybe the way i phase my question is wrong. somehow, i can't get what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you intend. It's identical to the code you published but takes the date from cell C1 instead of it being hard-coded.

```
Dim RefDate     As Variant

With ActiveSheet
    RefDate = .Range("C1").Value
    ' leave C1 blank if you need today's date
    ' or keep a formula ike =TODAY() there
    If Not IsDate(RefDate) Or RefDate = "" Then RefDate = Date
    
    RefDate = DateSerial(Year(RefDate), Month(RefDate), 1)
    .ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
                 Field:=2, _
                 Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
                 Criteria2:=Array(1, Format(RefDate, "m/d/yyyy"))
End With
```

If C1 is blank or doesn't contain a date the code will use the current date. The line `RefDate = DateSerial(Year(RefDate), Month(RefDate), 1)` changes the date - either taken from C1 or the current date - to the first date of the month indicated by it. So, on any day in April the date applied to the filter will be April 1, in May it will be May 1 etc. Therefore you can leave C1 blank or with the current date and change it only when you need the filter to use a date from another month.